# How to correctly code retainAll method on Java

Tags: java, linked-list

```
@Override
public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(c == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("collection is null");
    }
    Iterator itr = c.iterator();

    while( itr.hasNext())
    {   
        if(!c.contains(itr.next()))
        {
            itr.remove();
            return true;

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So basically  I want to invoke this method through a listA that has "Hey, 1 ,2, 3, 4, Bro ". And within the parameter of retainAll() I have a collection of an arraylist called listB with two elements "Hey" and "Bro". After invoking this method listA should only contain "Hey" and "Bro". I did some debugging but I don't know where the code is wrong. Any help will be great. So calling it will look like below

```
listA.retainAll(ListB)
```

Comment: I guess you do not want to leave your loop when the first non-matching item is encountered. If so, why did you put a `return` there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong list -  you iterate over the elements of `c` and check for each of them if it's contained in `c`, so you remove nothing (and if you did remove anything, you'd be removing it from the wrong list).

In addition, you shouldn't return `true` after removing the first element that should be removed, since you may have to remove multiple elements.

It should be:

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {  
    if(c == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("collection is null");
    }
    Iterator itr = iterator(); // i.e. iterate over this list

    boolean found = false;
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {   
        if(!c.contains(itr.next()))
        {
            itr.remove(); 
            found = true; 
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the guidance. After testing though, I get these exceptions `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at MyLinkedList$MyLinkedListIterator.remove(MyLinkedList.java:415)
 at MyLinkedList.retainAll(MyLinkedList.java:227)
 at MyLinkedListTester.testRetainAll(MyLinkedListTester.java:185)
 at MyLinkedListTester.main(MyLinkedListTester.java:486)`

Comment: @CenturiDamos you didn't show how you implement the `iterator()` method. If you return an `Iterator` that doesn't support `remove()`, you should add support to `remove()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer, after reviewing my iterator class, It seems I made the remove method throw an exception. Will work on the issue before seeking further guidance.